# Offline routing is not working

Tags: here-api

I'd like to use the offline routing feature so I downloaded the MapPackage of my region. I know the download went well because I can zoom on towns in the region offline and all details are shown).

But when I try to compute a route on this region, it does not work, and I get no error message. The onCalculateRouteFinished callback is just never called.

I'm using RouteManager#calculateRoute method (as for online calculation). Should I be using something else to make it work ?

I'm using an evaluation license, is it related ?

Thank you

edit to answer marco's comment:

I'm using "bretagne" region in france/europe.

```
RouteOptions ro = new RouteOptions();
ro.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK);
ro.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);

RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();
routePlan.setRouteOptions(ro);
-- addWaypoint (coord) called several times. all coords are in the bretagne region --


RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();
routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, new RouteManager.Listener(){            
        @Override
        public void onProgress(int i) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "progress " + index + ": " + i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCalculateRouteFinished(RouteManager.Error error, List<RouteResult> list) {
            if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not calculate route: " + error.name());
                return;
            }

            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                -- do something with result --
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, eval license should be fine and also calculate route is correct. Could you please show us the part of the code where you set up routemanager, routeplan, routeoptions and attach the listeners ? What country to you want to use for the routeplanning ?

Comment: I edited my question with the code your asking. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you please check if TransportMode.CAR would work for you ? I am not  sure how you test the offline scenario you mentioned in the beginning, but due to https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/routing-offline.html TransportMode.TRUCK is right now online only without offline capabilities.

Comment: It works in car mode, thank you!

Comment: Do you plan to add offline capabilities for TRUCK mode in the future ?

Comment: Yes, will come with the next release end of September

Comment: Hi @Teriblus, could you please share the code how you show that download region to a mapview? thank you.

Comment: I could share this code but since a newer release it's now possible to download a bounding box, and I think it's better since the dowload region feature is buggy (see david leong comment here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470647/getmappackageatcoordinate-never-return-smallest-package-for-some-regions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TransportMode.CAR instead of TRUCK fixed the problem. As stated by marco in the comments, offline routing is only available for cars.