# GetMapPackageAtCoordinate never return smallest package for some regions

Tags: android, here-api, offline-caching

I'm using the MapLoader#getMapPackageAtCoordinate method to find which offline package I should download. The thing is that I never want to download the country (France) package (for data usage consideration).

The documentation clearly says that for some coordinates, the method may not be able to find the smallest (region) package and return the country package instead. But I was expecting to be able to get the smallest package when trying with multiple geocoordinates in the region.

For some regions (Normandie, Bretagne, Nouvelle-Acquitaine), getMapPackageAtCoordinate almost always returns the region package. But for other regions (Ille-de-France, Pays-De-La-Loire), the France package is always returned.

Is there a way to improve this behaviour in order to get the region package ?

Thanks

Comment: From prior experience creating this particular API, do not use it. It is buggy and full of holes as you have found. Internally it does a reverse geocoding to find the country and then attempts to fuzzy match the result.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and precise advice. I wished I had known sooner but better late than never! What would you recommend instead? My use case is that the device needs offline maps but I want to download the fewest data possible and I do not know in advance where the vehicle will drive.

Comment: Store a list of bounding boxes for each region and then do an intersection with the area you would like to download. For example: https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540

Comment: In a previous version of my app I used the map package id in order to download a specific map package, assuming those ids will never change. But they did change (!!) this year and when they did new devices were unable to download the offline map. That's why I decided to rely on getMapPackageAtCoordinate. Now I'm wondering to do what you suggest using package names instead, but with no guarantee the names will not change in the future... Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest SDK version. Major loopholes and bugs are already fixed.

Available for both iOS and Android, HERE SDKs come in two editions. The Lite Edition provides a quick way to integrate location features into applications built for devices with limited ROM capabilities and rendering needs. The Premium Edition provides everything found in the Lite Edition, plus access to offline capabilities and other location features such as navigation for cars, trucks and pedestrians; electronic horizon, toll cost calculation, advanced data sets like speed limits, inclines, curvature, and more.

Please refer to do the documentation for more detail :

https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk